# opencv flann index assignment operator

Tags: c++, opencv, knn

I want to use `cv::flann::Index` as a class member and thus to assign value to it when necessary.

However, if there is a re-assignment of `Index`, I get "pointer being freed was not allocated" at `Index` destruction during execution. Is there a problem in its copy control or I misunderstand smth?

This works:

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(101508, 128, CV_32F);
cv::flann::Index
index = cv::flann::Index(mat, cv::flann::SavedIndexParams("myfile.bin"));
```

This doesn't work

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(101508, 128, CV_32F);
cv::Mat mat2 = cv::Mat(101508, 128, CV_32F);
cv::flann::Index 
index = cv::flann::Index(mat, cv::flann::SavedIndexParams("myfile.bin"));
index = cv::flann::Index(mat2, cv::flann::SavedIndexParams("myfile.bin"));
```

and even this doesn't work:

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(101508, 128, CV_32F);
cv::flann::Index 
index;
index = cv::flann::Index(mat, cv::flann::SavedIndexParams("myfile.bin"));
```

It is opencv 2.4.2